# Calculate retention rate split by year

Tags: r, database, split, retention, churn

Calculate retention rate / churn by year split

Dear Community, I am working on a data mining project where I would like to transform prior thinking from excel into R.

I have a customer database with contracts data and would like to calculate the retention rate.
I was playing around with these `library(lubridate)`; `library(reshape2)`; `library(plyr)` but I couldn't figure it out how it works in R.

I have data like this:

```r
ID    Customer        START          END
 1       Tesco   01-01-2000   31-12-2000
 2       Apple   05-11-2001   06-02-2002
 3         H&M   01-02-2002   08-05-2002
 4        Tesco  01-01-2001   31-12-2001
 5       Apple   01-01-2003   31-12-2004
```

I now was thinking of splitting the data into the Years (df2000, df2001) and then look it up again if the customer name exists in the main table (if yes return 1).

A result could look like this:

```r
Customer     2000    2001    2002  2003   Retention Rate
Tesco         1        1      0     0          0.5
Apple         0        1      0     1
H&M           0        0      1     0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you can try to get `year` value from each `START` date, `count` number of entries for each `Customer` and `year`, calculate the retention rate and `spread` the data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(year = format(as.Date(START, format = "%d-%m-%Y"), "%Y")) %>%
  dplyr::count(Customer, year) %>%
  group_by(Customer) %>%
  mutate(ret = n()/n_distinct(.$year))  %>%
  tidyr::spread(year, n, fill = 0) 

#  Customer   ret  `2000` `2001` `2002` `2003`
#  <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 Apple     0.5       0      1      0      1
#2 H&M       0.25      0      0      1      0
#3 Tesco     0.5       1      1      0      0
```

---

**EDIT**

To consider data with Fiscal year instead from Oct-Sep we can do

```
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(START = dmy(START), 
         START = if_else(month(START) >= 10, START + years(1), START),
         year = year(START)) %>%
  dplyr::count(Customer, year) %>%
  group_by(Customer) %>%
  mutate(ret = n()/n_distinct(.$year))  %>%
  tidyr::spread(year, n, fill = 0)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Customer = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L), .Label = c("Apple", "H&M", "Tesco"), class = "factor"), 
START = structure(c(1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("01-01-2000", 
"01-01-2001", "01-01-2003", "01-02-2002", "05-11-2001"), class = "factor"), 
END = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("06-02-2002", 
"08-05-2002", "31-12-2000", "31-12-2001", "31-12-2004"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak Shah, Thanks for the code it works! However, when I apply my real data I got the error: Fehler in as.Date.default(start, format = "%m/%d/%y") : do not know how to convert 'start' to class “Date”

Comment: @Lebowski are you using the correct name of the column? In your example it is `START` whereas your are using `start`, case matters.

Comment: You are a star! $

Comment: One other question: Rather than using start year. I would like to use the criteria Fiscal Year.
For instance if customer exists in table with a contract made one 2005 and contract was made in the range of 1.10.2004 - 30.9.2005 then return 1 in 2005.

Comment: @Lebowski Can you check the updated the answer after the **EDIT** ?